# How to lazy-load a sub-component after other vital components of same page loads in Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

The loadChildren attribute of Routes in Angular lazy loads the module but it cannot load a sub-component in that page resulting in a delayed page load speed.
Example:

```
<app-component-1>
    <app-component-2></app-component-2>
</app-component-1>
```

Here, I want the page to display as soon as possible, and I want app-component-2 to load after other parts of the page finish loading. Just like widgets, I want the main content to load fast and widgets to start loading after main content loads and is displayed.

Comment: You need custom preloading strategy. For example, you can delay it for some time. Here is an [example](https://medium.com/@muthudevendra/angular-custom-preloading-strategy-32abe99944f8)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @v.kostenko, however preloading strategy is good for loading the entire module which I already have implemented in my project. However I want to load smaller parts of the same page asynchronously.

Comment: So, I think you need [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and don't forget to set `module` to `esnext` in your tsconfig.json